# How to enable CORS while sending $.get requests from jquery?

Tags: java, jquery, tomcat, cors, jax-rs

I have set up a Tomcat 9 server hosting my API code. It is working fine when I call it from postman. I have also added the following filter to the Tomcat `conf/web.xml` file:

```xml
<filter>
<filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
<init-param>
<param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
<param-value>Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials</param-value>
</init-param>
</filter>
```

I am using the following jQuery code for sending a `GET` request:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $.get("http://localhost:8080/myapp/webapp/cars", function(data, status){
        alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
});
```

It throws the following error:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Is there anything I should do more on the server side to allow cross-origin requests?

How do I modify the above jQuery request to get rid of this error?

Many other posts have suggested to use an `ajax` method call with `dataType:"jsonp"`? Is it possible to somehow make that modification to the above `$.get` method? If not, please give example of a `GET` and `POST` to enable CORS using the `ajax` method.

---

**EDIT**

I also tried with following configuration:

```xml
<filter>
<filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
<init-param>
<param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
<param-value>*</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
<param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
<param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
<param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
<param-value>Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
<param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
<param-value>Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
<param-name>cors.support.credentials</param-name>
<param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
<param-name>cors.preflight.maxage</param-name>
<param-value>10</param-value>
</init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

…but it’s still not working.

Comment: You're not setting the init-param properly. See the [docs for the CorsFilter](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#CORS_Filter). You needs to set the `cors.allowed.origins` init-param to the origins you want to allow (or * for all origins)

Comment: @peeskillet Kindly refer to the ***EDIT*** in the question. Still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the headers when handling/creating the response with Tomcat.

```
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, OPTIONS");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
```

Response to the question `Where do I add this`:

You add it when you prepare your response for your servlet (i.e., the appropriate method, in the following example `POST`):

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    public void doPost(final HttpServletRequest request, 
                       final HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException {
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, OPTIONS");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
    }
}
```

If you don't have any servlet implemented and you want to do it via configuration (e.g., `init-parameters`) you may also be able to add it to your init-parameters, but make sure to have all there headers `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, `Access-Control-Allow-Methods`, `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` set, with the appropriate content.

If it's still not working it would help to see the headers that are set in the response, to determine which header may be set incorrectly.

Comment: Where do I add this?